# Error: html-pdf: PDF generation timeout. Phantom.js script did not exit

Tags: html, node.js

I'm building out a node api that uses the dynamic-html-pdf package (which uses PhantomJS). The function works fine on my local machine, but whenever I deploy the function on azure, I get the following error:

> Error: html-pdf: PDF generation timeout. Phantom.js script did not exit.

```
 var options = {
        format: "A3",
        orientation: "landscape",
        border: "10mm",
        timeout: "000"
    };

    var document = {
        type: 'buffer',
        template: html,
        context: {
            Wellsfargo: wellsfargo
        },
    };

    if (document === null) {
        return null;

    } else {
        pdf.create(document, options).then(response => {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=" + "wellsFargo.pdf",
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            });
            return res.end(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return res.status(200).send(error.toString());  
        });
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then i,set the default time of phanthomjs as timeout: "3000" it is working perfectly...

var options = {
format: "A3",
orientation: "landscape",
border: "10mm",
timeout: "3000"
};

```
var document = {
    type: 'buffer',
    template: html,
    context: {
        Wellsfargo: wellsfargo
    },
};

if (document === null) {
    return null;

} else {
    pdf.create(document, options).then(response => {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=" + "wellsFargo.pdf",
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        });
        return res.end(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(200).send(error.toString());
    });
};
```